# Slick 2.0 - generic enum mapper

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0, play-slick

I have problem with upgrading from Slick 1.0 to Slick 2.0 in my Play apllication.

In my app I have some User defined types example:

```scala
sealed trait UserStatus

case object NewUser extends UserStatus
case object ActiveUser extends UserStatus
case object BlockedUser extends UserStatus

object UserStatus extends SerializableEnum[UserStatus] {
  def mapping = Map[String, UserStatus](
    "NEW" -> NewUser,
    "ACTIVE" -> ActiveUser,
    "BLOCKED" -> BlockedUser
  )
}
```

and generic mapper for slick 1.0:

```scala
trait SerializableEnum[T] {
  def mapping: Map[String, T]

  def reverseMapping = mapping.map(_.swap)

  implicit def enumWrites = new Writes[T] {
    def writes(o: T): JsValue = JsString(reverseMapping(o))
  }

  implicit val enumReads = new Reads[T] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[T] = json match {
      case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(mapping(s))
      case _ => JsError("Enum type should be of proper type")
    }
  }
  implicit val enumTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[T, String](reverseMapping, mapping)
}
```

After migration to Slick 2.0, new mapper wasn't work:

```scala
trait SerializableEnum[T] {
  def mapping: Map[String, T]

  def reverseMapping:Map[T,String] = mapping.map(_.swap)

  implicit def enumWrites = new Writes[T] {
    def writes(o: T): JsValue = JsString(reverseMapping(o))
  }

  implicit val enumReads = new Reads[T] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[T] = json match {
      case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(mapping(s))
      case _ => JsError("Enum type should be of proper type")
    }
  }
  implicit val enumTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[T, String](reverseMapping, mapping)
}
```

Compiler says:

```
No ClassTag available for T
```

It is not possible to define ClassTag type for trait. Does anybody have idea how to resolve it?

I prepared example app for this:
https://github.com/mgosk/slick-test

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Same issue here.

Comment: Nope. I define mappings for each sealed trait ex: https://gist.github.com/mgosk/fd503adc1792cfff88ab